# Alternatives to adding JavaScript in anchor tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi StackOverflow community. I have a question about alternatives to adding JavaScript in the href of HTML anchor tags.  I already know this is poor practice and instead of doing this:

```
<div id="some_div"><a href="JavaScript:myfunction();">Text</a></div>
```

I can just do this:
    Text

```
$('#some_div').on("click","a",function(e){
  myFunction();
});
```

My question is, how does this work if you have to pass variables into the function?  For example:

```
<div id="some_div"><a href="JavaScript:myfunction('param1','param2')">Text</a></div>
```

Now keep in mind that the data in param1 and param2 will be different strings.  How do you handle this case?  The event listener needs to receive different data entered by the anchor tag.  So how would the user add the param1 and param2 data when they use:

```
<div id="some_div"><a href="#">Text</a></div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Depends on where the params will be coming from. Where do you have them? In the end, you'll be calling `myFunction(p1, p2);`

Comment: The params will be entered by data entry personnel.  I want them to enter them in the anchor.  Sadly this has to be backward compatible with IE7,8,&9.  I know that HTML5 doesn't work with IE7.

Comment: HTML5 may not work with IE7, however data-attributes do because they're just attributes.

Comment: So just to be clear, my apologies, you can create your own parameters "on the fly" with HTML tags?

Comment: Yes, however if you wanted your code to *"Validate"* then you have to follow standards. If you're using the html5 doctype, your page would validate with data attributes. What browser you are using doesn't matter when it comes to validation, and just because it doesn't validate doesn't mean it won't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you can do it.  One that comes to mind would be to use `data-*` attributes on the anchor:

```
<a href="#" data-param1="param1" data-param2="param2">Text</a>

var $this = $(this);
myFunction($this.data("param1"), $this.data("param2"));
```

Comment: Isn't that an HTML5 parameter?  This has to work with IE7 which doesn't handle HTML5.  Sorry I should have stated that above.

Comment: @seroth it will still work in IE7.  It is only valid in HTML5, but that doesn't mean that IE7 can't use the attribute.

Comment: It is html5, but it works in all browsers and versions of browsers. it's just an attribute.